# Show linux output in Visual Studio 22 + WSL

Tags: visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I succesfully linked visual studio with WSL (v1),
I can build an application and debug it, anyway if i use the "run only" (^F5) button I have only compile result and no execution prints but if I run in "debug mode" (F5) a "linux console window" opens on the bottom-left of the screen.

My question is: how do I make Visual studio open that linux console also when just running the application?

Note: I'm running VS 2022

Comment: Q: "Visual Studio" (the MSVS IDE) or "Visual Studio Code"?  They're very different :) Please change your tag if you're using VSCode.  And please clarify whether or not you've installed and configured the WSL extension for VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio ( Community ) V 17.4.5